# How to continue he execution of python script after user change

Tags: python, postgresql, python-2.7, subprocess, sudo

I want to execute following commands in sequence using a python script:

```
sudo su - postgres   #login as postgres user
psql
```

I tried using :

```
import os

cmd = 'sudo su - postgres'
os.system(cmd)

cmd1='psql'
os.system(cmd1)
```

The problem with this is that the 2nd command gets executed only after I log out from the postgres user, but I want to run it as postgres user. How can I can I continue the execution of python script after the user change?

Thanks

Comment: what's the goal ? managing a new schema or database from the "dba user" named postgres ?

Comment: @FoxMaSk: Creating a postgres database from dumpfile

Comment: `sudo -u postgres psql dbname < dump` does not do the trick ?

Comment: @FoxMaSk I'm using "cat dump | zcat - | PGPASSWORD=password psql -d voylla_development -h localhost -p 5432 -U user_name"

As I need localhost and port to be able to index solr by giving the url of the database. For this I need to enter the psql prompt

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
sudo su - postgres --command='cat … | psql …'
```

But you shouldn't. You should configure your database server to allow a user running your python script access to your database without password. Or at least use `.pg_pass` file in this user home directory to provide username and password for this database.

If you use PGPASSWORD, as you indicated in a comment, then any other user in your system can display it simply using `ps auxwww`.

Comment: Interesting. This would work. But is there a way to continue the execution of the script, to handle the cases where I need to execute multiple commands as a different user?